# How can I say "I wonder"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been missing the expression "I wonder" in Esperanto. The best I could come up with so far is "Mi scivolas", but I feel like that is "I want to know" or "I'm curious whether...". Would "mi demandas min mem" work? Are there other suitable phrases?

Comment: Can we get a full example sentence for context?

Answer (score 7):

**Mi demandas min** = I ask myself. So it seems to make sense.

These English definitions are from the Google dictionary for the word **Wonder** as a verb. The Esperanto is my translation.

> desire or be curious to know something.

Mi scivolas.

> used to express a polite question or request.

Ĉu vi estas certa ...

> feel doubt.

Mi dubas.

> feel admiration and amazement; marvel.

Mi miras.

> be surprised.

Mi supriziĝas.

Comment: Kurioza: Ekscitanta la intereson, scivolecon per sia malofteco, eksterordinareco, laŭ PIV. If kuriozi was a verb that should mean esti kurioza which is a different thing than someone being curious.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen *mi demandis min* several times before. I don't know whether there are better alternatives.